# Android:How to apply multiple styles to a layout?

Tags: android, styles

In my App I have provided an option to apply a style to edit the background color of an activty. However how do I a add an additional spinner option to change font style? I could create a theme to cover every combination of background and font style but this would become unwieldy as more colors or styles are added. Does anyone have any guidance?

```
<style name ="redBody">
         <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name ="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name ="redTitle">
         <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name ="android:background">@color/red</item>
    </style>

    <style name ="blueBody">
         <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkBlue</item>
        <item name ="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name ="blueTitle">
         <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name ="android:background">@color/darkBlue</item>
    </style>

    <style name ="greenBody">
         <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
        <item name ="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name ="greenTitle">
         <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name ="android:background">@color/green</item>
    </style>

    <style name = "Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        </style>

    <style name = "Theme.Red" >
        <item name="textTitle">@style/redTitle</item>
        <item name="textBody">@style/redBody</item>

        </style>

    <style name = "Theme.Blue" >
        <item name="textTitle">@style/blueTitle</item>
        <item name="textBody">@style/blueBody</item>

        </style>
    <style name = "Theme.Green">
        <item name="textTitle">@style/greenTitle</item>
        <item name="textBody">@style/greenBody</item>

        </style>
```